# C++ MySQL Connector in Xcode 5

Tags: c++, mysql, xcode, exc-bad-access, mysql-connector

I have a problem using MySQL Connector for C++ in Xcode 5.

When I use the `sql::Driver->connect` I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`

What I have:

- 64bit Boost libs (working)
- 64bit Mysqlconnector (dylib) + header files (which are in Xcode)
- `libmysqlcppconn.7.dylib` and `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` are copied to the binaries directory for being loaded (if I don't have them there, it tells me it cannot find the images.)
- Compiled with 64bit Intel

What I do:

```
try
{
    sql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance();


    driver->connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD);

    m_databaseConnection = driver->connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD);
    m_databaseConnection->setAutoCommit(true);
    m_databaseConnection->setSchema(DBDATABASE);

    return true;
}
catch (...)
{
    return false;
}
```

I've set a breakpoint above `driver->connect` and recognized that `driver` is set, so `get_driver_instance()` seems to work.
When calling its `connect` method, `driver` becomes `NULL` and the program crashes with bad access.

How can I solve this?

Comment: In case this never got resolved, see the following post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280499/mysql-connector-c-os-x-10-9-mavericks-and-xcode-5-0-2