# MySQL XCode C++ Connector Bad Access code=13

Tags: c++, mysql, xcode, exc-bad-access, mysql-connector

I have a problem with getting MySQL working with my code. I get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)` error on the connect line.

The code is the following:

```
 try {

     driver =sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
     connection = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306/", "root", "");
```

I've seen the post [MySQL Connector/C++ OS X 10.9 Mavericks and XCODE 5.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280499/mysql-connector-c-os-x-10-9-mavericks-and-xcode-5-0-2) but I can't do the same thing because I use a bunch of libraries that were linked the same way, and they are more difficult to configure in Xcode then probably adding MySQL to my project.