# OSX: Build MySQL C++ Connector

Tags: c++, mysql, macos, cmake, mysql-connector

I've downloaded the mysql connector c++ for OSX in order to build it. I was experiencing the problem in  [MySQL XCode C++ Connector Bad Access code=13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236545/mysql-xcode-c-connector-bad-access-code-13), so I followed the [MySQL Connector/C++ OS X 10.9 Mavericks and XCODE 5.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280499/mysql-connector-c-os-x-10-9-mavericks-and-xcode-5-0-2) solution.

The problem is that when I execute the `cmake` as is described in the README file and in the previous post i get:

`CMake Error: The source directory` (...)`/mysql-connector-c++-1.0.5-osx10.5-x86-64bit" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

First I searched for the file in the children directories but no luck. I've googled this error but I couldn't get an solution to it. Can you help me?

Comment: You have probably downloaded binary package instead of source code.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a very old topic but I ran into this issue just now and I'd like to share my answer in case someone else stables upon this. You can get the source from git using:

```
git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp.git
```